# Specific records locked for update after rake task on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, pg

I have a really weird error and I can't seem to fix it.

Basically I ran a rake task which updated all phone numbers on a site to themselves to take advantage of phony normalisation

i.e. they were all in different formats for few thousand records, and by applying client.update attributes(phone: client.phone) ...etc This then got them all into a consistent format.

However, it worked on everything but two records. And now I can't update any field on those records.

Completely confused... 
Can't update through the app
Can't update through console with c.phone = X c.save
Can't update through console with c.update_attributes(phone:...etc)

Anyone run into this before. 
Using heroku CEDAR stack with PINK pg db.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 
It was a validation issue based on a bug with phony and the way it was dealing with certain types of UK numbers.

For anybody else who ends up panicking that their database has locked up some records...

```
client.update_attribute :phone, '44123456789'
```

or something similar will test whether the record will update whilst ignoring all the validation so at least you can exclude that as the problem.